# Populate POJO from Excel row

Tags: java, apache-poi, cyclomatic-complexity

I am using Apache POI to read an Excel file having many columns. I have a POJO in which there is a field for each column in Excel sheet.

How do I populate my POJO with values from Excel achieving minimum cyclomatic complexity?

I had implemented really crude approach of having `switch..case` for populating my POJO, but this results in tight coupling and gives rise to high cyclomatic complexity, giving below my implementation for reference (this is I feel very dirty implementation) :

```
    // Iterate over cells in a row
    for (Cell cell : row) {
        cellValue = getCellValue(cell);

        if (cellValue == null) {
        continue;
        }

        // Populate model
        data = populateModel(data, cell.getColumnIndex(), cellValue);
    }
```

**called method:**

```
    /*
     * Populates pojo
     */
    private MyData populateModel(MyData data, int columnIndex, Object cellValue) {
    switch (columnIndex) {
        case 0:
        data.setAccount((long) cellValue);
        break;
        case 1:
        data.setDocNumber((long) cellValue);
        break;
        case 2:
        data.setType((String) cellValue);
        break;
        // more cases for subsequent excel columns
        default:
        // do nothing
       }
    return data;
    }
```

Comment: check out data unmarshalling.  Also you can convert the excel file to XML and use something like JAXB to unmarshall the data to POJOs.

Comment: If you don't have calculations in Excel , convert to CSV and use Smooks [link]http://www.smooks.org/guide[link]  tools for data mapping, its high performing  and mapping logic will be configurable

Comment: Why not hand over your `populateModel` the whole [Row](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html)? Then you can get the appropriate `Cell`s having the appropriate column indexes using [Row.getCell](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#getCell-int-).